# Symfony Doctrine JoinTable

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

How to JoinTable in DB if I have relation OneToOne->ManyToOne?

I have Data Base MySQL and in table users I need see row client_id. But now I have row user_id in table clients, thats all. But need clien_id in table users. I Post this is question in issue in github in doctrinebundle because this is annotation @ORM\JoinColumn

In entity when ManyToOne I have filed in DB entity_id, but I need entity_id in OneToMany too, I try

```
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="developer_id", nullable = true, referencedColumnName="id")
```

but in DB not see this column

this my entity Clients in DB I have user_id

```
/**
 * Clients.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="clients")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Repository\ClientsRepository")
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Clients
{
use Timestampable;
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users", inversedBy="client", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $user;
```

And this my entity Users (not column client_id):

```
/**
 * Users.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Repository\UsersRepository")
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
 class Users
{
use Timestampable;
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Clients", mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", nullable = true, referencedColumnName="id")
 */
public $client;
```

Comment: I do not understand your problem. Which association do you want to add? And what is the actual issue?

Comment: I have Data Base MySQL and in table users I need see row client_id. But now I have row user_id in table clients, thats all. But need clien_id in table users. I Post this is question in issue in github in doctrinebundle because this is annotation @ORM\JoinColumn

Comment: I still do not completely understand what you try to achieve. Currently you have clients and users and each client can have one user, right? But you want it the other way around (i.e. one user can only be associated with one client, but a client can be associated with many users)?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Clarify please what you're expect to receive? For example:
`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update` will generate desired tables for you, or entity `Users` will be joined to `Clients` when you create new Users instance or else...

Comment: ManyToOne create column automatic and this is ok. But is there a possibility column in table user, where relation OneToMany. I add annotation but in DB not see row in table user. In table client all well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you little bit confused with your relations...

Try this:

Clients:

```
class Clients
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

Users:

```
class Users
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Clients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    public $client;
}
```

Now, if you'll run: `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` in your db will be created tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_1483A5E919EB6921` (`client_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_1483A5E919EB6921` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `clients` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Suppose it's exactly what you're expect...

Of course all this true, if i correctly understood your question...

(btw better rename your entities to User and Client.)

Comment: ManyToOne create column automatic and this is ok. But is there a possibility column in table user, where relation OneToMany. I add annotation but in DB not see row in table user. In table client all well.

Comment: No, it isn't possible. Because in case OneToMany you don't need column `client_id` in `users`, you'll need column `user_id` in `clients`, and doctrine will create it for you.

Comment: Why it's bad? Maybe you're need redesign your db schema... Because it's common practice...

Comment: schema ok, but for the convenience of the customer, wants to see client_id

Comment: I think you try to build something wronf...
For example: we have table `category` and this should know nothing about any other tables. And it's great!) And we have table `product` and it know about `category`, because many products can have same category, that's why table product contains field `category_id`, because product know about category... To receive category from product you can write something like: `$product->getCategory()->getId();`. Everyone build schemas in such style and it works!)

Comment: To receive all products from category, you can write something like this:
`$em->createQueryBuilder()->select('c, p')->from('AppBundle:Category', 'c')->leftJoin('AppBundle:Product', 'p', Join::WITH, 'c.id = p.categoryId')->getQuery()->getArrayResult()
;`